# Audio can be heard only in VLC player, but not in the editor

Tags: audio, codec

I have few files that I did retrieve from webpages, and saved as MKV files.

VLC play them without problems, but when I load the file either in the Windows video editor, or in Power director 13, the video play but there is no audio.

I am not sure why I can't even convert the file from VLC, since even using the conversion engine that is integrated in VLC, the resulting file has video but no audio.

My understanding is that if the video player can play it, then the system has the right codec, so why neither windows video editor nor Power director 13 are not able to play the audio?

Comment: How do you 'retrieve' the files? Paste the readout of [Mediainfo](http://mediaarea,net) for one of them. Use View -> Text mode.

Comment: The video was on a webpage; I did right click and downloaded it. The resulting saved file is a MKV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.MKV files are not a friendly video format when working with NLE systems. And the non existent audio you're getting is probably due to the way audio  in .MKV files are wrapped.

I would suggest transcoding the .MKV file(s) to .mp4 if you're working with Windows Movie Maker. Alternatively you can follow this link for suitable formats: [video files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/15289/windows-movie-maker-file-types)

A really good transcoder (free) is [adaptor](https://www.macroplant.com/adapter/). It will read your .MKV file without problems and should convert to a .mp4 file just as easily.

Be sure to crank up the bit rate to get the best possible picture :)

Comment: The video is recognized, why transcode it?

Comment: Perhaps you'd want to want work with a file where the video & audio are intact. As opposed to working with a separate audio and video file.

Comment: Still don't follow - OP needs to either copy both video and audio to compatible container like MOV or copy video and transcode audio to MOV. There's no suggestion of separate files being generated or used,

Comment: When editing you want to work with both audio and video. Convert to a file that does, i.e. .mp4 or .mov, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, adaptor was actually able to recognize the audio track (neither windows editor, nor handbrake were able to), so I did convert it in a more friendly mp4, so now I can edit it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mulvya: I can see the video but I can't edit it, this is why I want to transcode it. Since none of the software that I used, were able to transcode the audio, I did post here to find out a solution.

Comment: adapter is a frontend for FFmpeg. If you post the Mediainfo readout, I can provide the ffmpeg command which will avoid re-encoding the video.

Comment: UserJMAtron and newbiez, Mulvya meant why *transcode* the video, when the problem was getting to the audio in the container. All that should be needed is to *rewrap* into another container. Transcoding the video would just add another codec cycle for no gain.

Comment: I see, although it should not count as transcoding video, if the video is left as original source, isn't it? I did leave everything as source for the video, so I assumed that I won't have another encoding pass on the source video stream

Comment: @Mulvya, I would like to post the data but I did convert the video already, so I did delete the source. The web page where I did get the video is long gone :(